# fortity scan :Mass Assignment: Request Parameters Bound into Persisted Objects

Tags: java

This is the scan. How can I solve this issue(line 23).
Thank you for you help!

InspSecretEntity.java:23（Mass Assignment: Request Parameters Bound into Persisted Objects）

```
20 * @version V1.0  
21 *
22 */
23@Entity
24@Table(name = "insp_secret", schema = "")
25@DynamicUpdate(true)
26@DynamicInsert(true)
27@SuppressWarnings("serial")
28public class InspSecretEntity implements java.io.Serializable {
29 /**codeid*/
30 private java.lang.String secretid;
...
```

Answer (score 0):

This vulnerability is flagged by fortify when a persisted object like an entity is used for API conversation. The request param should be converted to VO/BO and then via mapper it should be translated to a DAO object.

An alternative would be to explicitly define which attributes on the request bound object are settable via request parameters.

e.g.

annotate with @JsonIgnore the property itself

annotate with @JsonIgnore its set method

annotate with @JsonProperty its get method